# Our website is being blocked and we don't know why

Tags: domain-name-system, php, domain, wordpress

I hope this question has never been asked before. Our website is being blocked by certain routers or ISPs (we can't tell). We are hosted in Singapore (AWS) and we use Cloudflare to host our DNS. Our website is http://www.nibble.id.

On our office internet/router it works fine. On all our team members personal home internet it works fine. However, on some shared internet (free public wifi, restaurant wifi, office wifi), our website is blocked. The DNS can't be looked up.

We recently tried to sign up for an AdSense account and even Google can't look up our website.

Our developers are certain everything is OK and we're really scratching our heads on this one. We would really appreciate any sort of insight on what might be going on. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your DNSSEC setup is incorrect/incomplete. See here: http://dnsviz.net/d/nibble.id/dnssec/

Per [Google standards](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/troubleshooting#step1) their DNS servers will report lookup failure if DNSSEC validation fails.

Also note that you only have an A record for nibble.id, not www.nibble.id, so the latter won't work regardless of any blacklisting or other issues.

Comment: Jeremy's advice is good. Also check if your public IP address is on one of the blacklists or on one of the stolen IP lists.

Comment: @JohnHanley: Jeremy's answer already found the problem, so there's no reason to believe the IP is blacklisted.

Comment: @EsaJokinen, you are probably correct. However, I have seen similar issues twice this year with APAC IP addresses and I expect that this problem will continue to get worse.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your responses. We will try following Jeremy's advice. We will keep you posted on the results.